# __init__.py is not turning the module into a package

Tags: python, packaging

I'm not sure if this is a silly question but I have no experience with packaging and stuff like these. Here is the tree structure with the files:

```
.
├── main.py
└── stringfunc
    ├── __init__.py
    └── toLower.py
```

main.py:

```py
    import sys
    import stringfunc

    def main():
      print(stringfunc.toLower.to_lower(sys.argv[1]))
      return 0

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()

toLower.py:

    def to_lower(inStr):
      return inStr.lower()
```

and the `__init__.py` file is empty.
Isn't the `stringfunc` directory supposed to behave like a package now when it has an `__init__.py` file? I know I could use *`from .toLower import to_lower`* in the `__init__.py` for an easier and less ugly way, but I just see in a book that this code must work as well, but it doesn't. So I'm afraid I don't understand how it really works.

Here's the error:

> AttributeError: module 'stringfunc' has no attribute 'toLower'

Obviously it's still considered a "module" and not a "package" by Python.

Comment: to use `stringfunc` as a package and use different functions you need to load thoe function in the __init__ file , so in your __init__.py file load `import toLowe`

Comment: @sahasrara62 thanks but I think Cireo and I tried that and it doesn't work on Python3. On Python3 toLower has to be imported absolutely.

Comment: just in your `__init__.py` file write `from . import toLower` and then do the thing you were doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done almost everything you needed to.  However, imports do not automatically take all paths and expose them. You would need to do one of:

- Import `stringfunc.toLower`
- Add `toLower` into `__init__.py`

To expand on the "Add `toLower`" option:

```
foo/__init__.py
# py2k
> from foobar import foobarval
> import foobaz
# py3k
> from foo.foobar import foobarval
> import foo.foobaz as foobaz

foo/foobar.py
> foobarval = 1

foo/foobaz.py
> foobazval = 2
```

```
$ python -c 'import foo; print(foo.foobarval)'
1
```

```
$ python -c 'import foo; print(foo.foobaz.foobazval)'
2
```

Comment: First one is working! Thanks! But can you explain the second one? (Add toLower into `__init__.py`) you mean I *import* it there? Because once I did and it gave the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toLower'`

Comment: I assume you tried to do an absolute import in `__init__.py`, which won't work because you won't have a module until init finishes loading.  You can do relative imports though.

Comment: No I didn't do an absolute import. Thanks for the edit and for your time. But I still get the same error even when I use the exact same structure you have put in your edit. 1_ I add `import toLower` in my `__init__.py` file and then 2_I run this: `python -c 'import stringfunc; print(stringfunc.toLower.to_lower("ABC"))'`. But I get the same error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toLower'`. Maybe I'm making a silly mistake. Also I didn't quite get the part that you said: "*__you won't have a module__ until init finishes loading*". Of course I didn't absolute import in it anyway.

Comment: Ah sorry, this is a py27 vs py3k issue.  You *must* put the absolute import for py3k

Comment: Oh... so that was the problem... I guess Python interprets the relative imports inside the package with respect to the initial point where an import has occured (in this example, in main.py), right...? Thank you very much.